# Should "invoke-rc.d" or "service" be used to restart services?

Tags: linux, debian, linux-mint, services, init-script

I'm confused as to which is best and in which circumstances:

```
invoke-rc.d apache2 restart
```

or

```
service apache2 restart
```

Is there a real difference?

`man service` has the following interesting bit:

> service runs a System V init script in as predictable environment as possible, removing most environment variables and with current working directory set to /.

I'm interested mainly in Debian, but also Mint (also based on Debian).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The official Debian [wiki page on daemons](https://wiki.debian.org/Daemon) says to use `service`:

```
# service ssh restart
Restarting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
```

Functionally `service` and `invoke-rc.d` are mostly equivalent, however:

- `invoke-rc.d` is the preferred command for packages' maintainer scripts, according to the command's man page
- `service` has a unique `--status-all` option, that queries status of all available daemons

It seems like `service` is the user-oriented command, while `invoke-rc.d` is there for other uses.

Answer (score 1):

Problem could be because your script is trying to use invoke-rc.d (which doesn't work because there are no runlevels in a docker container) before trying the service command (which will work).
So change the if conditions in the script or the lazy way is make it look for a non-existent path so it will use the service command. eg:

`if [ -x /xxxusr/sbin/invoke-rc.d ]; then
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d $OMSAGENT_WS start
elif [ -x /sbin/service ]; then
/sbin/service $OMSAGENT_WS start`